# Retrieve textfield.text which is inside custom cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have tableview which has custom cells.
Each cell has 3 textfields: dayInWeek, startTime, endTime.
In below image, it has 2 rows. But user can click + button to add more rows.

If user click Submit button, I want to loop to every rows, collect 3 textfields data, and store in array or whatever.

[image]

Custom TableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class RegularScheduleCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dayInWeek: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var startTime: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var endTime: UITextField!
      
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code


    }
}
```

And a view controller:

```
import UIKit


class RegularScheduleVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    
    var numOfRow = 1
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numOfRow
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "RegularScheduleCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RegularScheduleCell
        
        return cell   
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
            
           numOfRow -= 1
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.right)
           
        tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
   
    
    func insertNewRow(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if numOfRow < 7 {
            numOfRow += 1
            tableView.reloadData()
            
        }
        
       

    }
    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    }
    
    
}
```

At this moment, I try to use UITextFieldDelegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "RegularScheduleCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RegularScheduleCell
        
        cell.dayInWeek.delegate = self
        cell.startTime.delegate = self
        cell.endTime.delegate = self
        return cell
```

and

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        allCellsText.append(textField.text!) //allCellsText is an array
        print(allCellsText) 
    }
```

so that when user finish editing, then add that data to array.
However, this does not satisfy my requirement, because:

- on the same cell: can not know if the data is belong to dayOfWeek, or startTime, or endTime
- on 2 different cells: can not know if data is belong to, let say, dayOfWeek of 1st cell or dayOfWeek of 2nd cell.

Therefore, How can I loop to all cells, get all 3 text fields data?
Thanks

Comment: You can't loop over the cells since cells that are offscreen aren't available.  You need to store your data in your view controller (e.g. in an array).  Create a protocol so that your view controller is a delegate of your custom cell and have the custom cell call an appropriate delegate method when the text changes so that the view controller can update the data model

Comment: If you create data source array of a cell data class, you will be able to pass the object to the cell, then assign value to it, after submit you can just read the array that have the object for textfield value

Comment: You can add indexpath.row as tag to cell using [textField setTag:<youCustomTag>] and then in your delegate method textFieldDidEndEditing get that tag which will be the position in your array and then update on that position

Comment: thanks for all comments. Honestly, I am new to iOS dev. Can anybody post an answer with code so that I can follow better?

Comment: @John is your issue resolved?

Comment: not yet. I am trying to understand each answer and implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Make an array of key pairs as-

```
    var arrayOfKeyPairs = [[String:Any]]()

    arrayOfKeyPairs.append(["header":"xx",
                            "value" : "",
                            “id”: "dsd",
                            "order" : 0])
```

We are just replacing the default values with user input values as-

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let center: CGPoint = textField.center
        let rootViewPoint: CGPoint = textField.superview!.convert(center, to: tableView)
        let indexPath: IndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: rootViewPoint)! as IndexPath
        arrayOfKeyPairs[indexPath.row ]["value"] = textField.text//here you are appending(replacing) data to array
}
```

On click of submit button, cross check what you received as-

```
func tapsOnNext(){
  self.view.endEditing(true)//for adding last text field value with dismiss keyboard
  print(arrayOfKeyPairs)
}
```

**Method 2:**
We can get cell data by accessing the cell with particular `indexpath` as

```
func tapsOnNext(){
     let indexpath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
     let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
     print(cell.myTextField.text)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get text of `UITextField` with adding target to `UITextField`

```
cell.YOUR_TEXTFIELD.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

//EditingChanged is one of the events and will be fired whenever the user changes any character in that UITextField.
```

After that, you can call your function like this:

```
 func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    //your code
}
```

Don't forget to create class for `UITableViewCell` and to create `IBOutlet`s of all your `UITextField` in that custom `cell` class

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way. 
First of all you can create an object for example "History"
make its properties like daysInWeek, startTime, endTime.

In your viewDidLoad method you define an array of Objects. Populate the data in the array, or save those objects of "History" that you created in this array.
Set the dataSource of the table view to this array.
in your method cellForRowAtIndexPath you can access the elements of the array you created above.

When you are tapping the plus button, you can create a new object of History, save this object in the array and reload the table view.

If you can share the git repo of this code, i will show how this is being done.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple code:  On button click get cell data from cell's text field**

```
 let indexpath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
 let cell = ItemtableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
 print("text \(cell.myTextField.text)")
```